# How to sum an array value at specific index ranges

Tags: javascript

How to sum using index value like mod, such an array

```
var arr = [
    "Player ", "1", "Player ", "2", "Player ", "3", "Position", "In/Our", 
    "Position", "In/Our", "Position", "In/Our", "2", "1", "11", "0", "10", 
    "0", "6", "0", "10", "1", "5", "1", "8", "1", "11", "1", "11", "0", "3"];
```

I want to calculate all value that divisibility by 6 regarding index.

Comment: Consider trying something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var words = ["Player ", "1", "Player ", "2", "Player ", "3", "Position", "In/Our", "Position", "In/Our", "Position", "In/Our", "2", "1", "11", "0", "10", "0", "6", "0", "10", "1", "5", "1", "8", "1", "11", "1", "11", "0", "3"];
var index=0;
var results = words.filter(word => {index= words.indexOf(word,index)+1;return ((index-1) % 6) == 0;});
console.log(results);
```

Then you can do what ever you want with the results array which contain only elements of index dividable by 6

Answer (score 1):

use `reduce`:

```
arr.reduce((acc, ele) => parseInt(ele) % 6 == 0 ? acc + parseInt(ele) : acc, 0)
```